# Why does this css style appear opaque in Chrome developer tools?

Tags: css, html, google-chrome, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

Using `Chrome developer tools` I added a `CSS` rule for a certain tag with certain `ID`. But this appears opaque. Why is it the case? Does this convey some special meaning in `Chrome developer tools`?
[image]

Comment: Please post a code example.

Answer (score 1):

It means that the rule has been inherited:

https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/elements-styles?csw=1#computed_style